# Difficulty in Testing Response Header Fields Other Than Status Code

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I am using the Express framework. The task is to retrieve a collection from the database and insert a customized message into the response header returned to the client (the Node.js code shown below works and I can see my customized message in the returning header):

```
if (req.accepts('json')) {
    **res.header('Warning', 'my_customized_message');**
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(res.locals.items, 200);
}
```

Now, I try to use "mocha" to unit test this line of newly added code using MOCHA:

```
request = require('request');
should = require('should');

describe('GET /core/dbq/534e930204dd311822ec1c9d', function() {
    this.timeout(15000);
    it ('Check header message', function(done) {
        request.get('http://localhost:3001/ecrud/v1/core/dbq/534e930204dd311822ec1c9d', function(err, response, header) {
            response.statusCode.should.equal(200);                                     
            response.warning.should.equal('my_customized_message');   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined
            done();
        } )
    } )
} )
```

If I test the response.statusCode only, there is no problem.  The MOCHA test passes successfully.  But, if I test the response.warning, I get an error saying the property 'should' is not defined  ( I have run npm should --save-dev).  It looks that "warning" is not recognized as a field of the "response".  But, "warning" is one of the response fields.

The same error happens if I try to test the  response.contentType.  I thought "Content-Type" is a very well known response header field.  Anyway, what I am really interested in is to test the "Warning" header.  Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Test Response Header Message Using MOCHA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159388/unit-test-response-header-message-using-mocha)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this instead (`response` is an [http.IncomingMessage](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage)):

```
response.headers.warning.should.equal('my_customized_message');
```